# Is there a way for me to hook up my headphones ( regular headphone jack ) via Bluetooth?

Tags: headphones, cable, wireless, cable+, converter

Do these adapters exist?

I'd plug my headphones jack (male) into the bluetooth connector (female), then connect to my HDTV via bluetooth. This way I can lay in bed with my WIRED headphones on, wirelessly connected via bluetooth.

I tried looking, but all I could find were male bluetooth adapters, not female, like this.

[image]

I need the opposite, but don't know what to search for on Amazon?

Comment: If the above (male) device is available, can you not get a female to female audio jack to connect it to your male headphone jack?

Comment: This answer is so old, I don't remember. I would be surprised if I didn't think of this since it's so obvious, so I figure there was some problem there. However, I can't think of any problem now...so maybe I just didn't think of this. So IDK. Thx for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they exist. Here is one from Sony.

[Sony’s DRC-BT30P Bluetooth Headphone Adapter Let’s You Use Your Existing Earbuds](http://www.gadgetreview.com/sonys-drc-bt30p-bluetooth-headphone-adapter-lets-you-use-your-existing-earbuds)

Comment: Is this the only product that exists to do this?

It seems to be a Japan-Only product, and hard to find. (Thus on Amazon/Ebay it is only sold by third parties for a very high price.)

If this is the only product that exists, the answer needs to be edited from "Yes, they exist. Here is one" to "Yes, one exists. Here it is"